# Disabling FK constraints with sp_msforeachtable gives FK errors

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've just added about 80 "missing" foreign keys to a legacy db and (unsurprisingly) the database re-create script now fails when dropping tables due to FK constraints. The strategy has always been to drop tables in a natural order and this has worked up to now. I don't want to maintain this approach and have tried disabling all FK constraints like this:

```
USE MYDB;
GO

EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
GO

DROP TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Table2]
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Table3]
...

exec sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
GO
```

The problem is I'm still getting errors:

> Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 Could not drop object
>   'dbo.Table1' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. Msg
>   3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 18 Could not drop object 'dbo.Table2'
>   because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong? I'm using SQL Server 2008 r2 on Windows 7.

Edit: I have noticed that I have a circular reference, i.e. Table1 has an FK to Table2, and vice versa, but even so....

Comment: Disabling the FK constraints is not enough. You would need to actually drop them to avoid this error.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I've copied a sp_dropconstraint stored proc which does the necessary work before the table is dropped. I guess what I really want is some code which will organise my drop table commands into an order where they'll work. Although the circular reference is going to be a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could drop all the constraint before running the drop table commands.  Something like this at the top of your script should work.

```
   declare @newLine as varchar(1) = char(13);
   declare @sqlCmd as varchar(max) = '';

   SELECT @sqlCmd = @sqlCmd + 'alter table ' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + ' drop constraint ' + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) + ';' + @newLine
   FROM sys.objects
   WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
         and OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) not in ('list','of','tables','to','ignore')
  order by case when left(OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),2) = 'PK' then 1 else 0 end
  exec (@sqlCmd)
  go
```

Comment: The problem is that I try the code from the answer, then get "The constraint 'PK_xxxxx' is being referenced by table 'Tablexxx', foreign key constraint 'XPKxxxxxxxxx'",. It doesn't seem to matter what I do, something fails. I can't drop a table because of a constraint, and can't drop a constraint because it's being referenced by a table. It seems like no-win situation. I've spent the best part of a day trying to get my scripts running reliably.

Comment: Looks like the error is caused by the primary key constraint. I changed the SQL command to drop those last.  Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks, that was it. This works reliably for me. I'm using LIKE 'FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT'.